# Neo4j and Django

Tags: django, python-3.x, neo4j, neomodel

Is ist possible to use [neomodel](https://github.com/robinedwards/neomodel) to make models in django?
How do I have to integrate neo4j in django? I'm using Python 3, so neo4django isn't really an option. 
I'm new to both of them and at the moment I'm a little confused...

Thanks a lot! :3

Comment: https://github.com/scholrly/neo4django

Answer (score 1):

Hey neomodel supports python 3 out of the box you can use it with or without django checkout the documentation here: http://neomodel.readthedocs.org/en/latest/

Comment: Yeah, but how do I work with neo4j in django? I just don't have an idea how to do that. I know how to use neomodel more or less, but I don't know more than the basics of the basics of django. Also my english isn't the best.

Comment: So my problem is, that I have no idea how to access the database in the settings.py in django. There is this Dictionary called DATABASES, but I don't know how to tell django that I want to use neo4j.

Comment: hi @kater any solutions or code snippets ?? you solved it right?

Answer (score 0):

```
NEOMODEL_NEO4J_BOLT_URL = bolt://neo4j:password@localhost:7687
NEOMODEL_SIGNALS = True
NEOMODEL_FORCE_TIMEZONE = False
NEOMODEL_ENCRYPTED_CONNECTION = True
NEOMODEL_MAX_POOL_SIZE = 50
```

You need to add the above lines in your settings.py file to use Neo4j.

Answer (score 0):

Hey I know this was asked 8 years ago, but now there's a tool called [neomodel](https://neomodel.readthedocs.io/en/latest/index.html) which serves this exact purpose. It can also be combined with [django-neomodel](https://github.com/neo4j-contrib/django-neomodel) which allows for neomodel to be easily integrated into your django project.

Using django-neomodel, all you need to do is specify the URL of the database in your `settings.py` file like so:

```py
NEOMODEL_NEO4J_BOLT_URL = 'bolt://{username}:{password}@{HOSTorIP}'
```

You can easily create models in your `models.py` file. Here are some examples for this [neomodel documentation](https://neomodel.readthedocs.io/en/latest/getting_started.html):

```py
from neomodel import (StructuredNode, StringProperty,
                      UniqueIdProperty, IntegerProperty,
                      RelationshipTo)

class Country(StructuredNode):
    code = StringProperty(unique_index=True, required=True)

class Person(StructuredNode):
    uid = UniqueIdProperty()
    name = StringProperty(unique_index=True)
    age = IntegerProperty(index=True, default=0)

    # traverse outgoing IS_FROM relations, inflate to Country objects
    country = RelationshipTo(Country, 'IS_FROM')
```

Then you can run `python manage.py install_labels` to do the equivalent of running migrations, or `python manage.py clear_neo4j` to clear all nodes from the database.

Nodes can be created like so:

```py
from models import Person

john = Person(name="john", age=23).save()
frank = Person(name="frank", age=50).save()

canada = Country(code=5).save()
```

And relationships like so:

```py
john.country.connect(canada)
```

And nodes/relationships can be retrieved as follows:

```py
frank = Person.nodes.get(name='frank')
frank.age += 1
frank.save()

franks_country = frank.country
print(franks_country)
# {'code': 5}
```